# Why am I getting an error with Dir in a VBA loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been building a macro to loop through a series of files in a folder and with each one copy and paste data into a series of other sheets in another folder. I started with this code below which worked fine doing the copy and pasting:

```
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However I've now added a second loop to deal with the multiple to multiple files and I'm getting a run time error 5 on the second version of:

`myFile = Dir`

I've renamed myFile to another name so it doesn't conflict with the first.

I've not posted all my code here as it's much longer and more complicated. Hope this is enough for you guys to go on?

Comment: If you need two directories open at the same time you need to investigate the much more flexible scripting.filesystemobject.

Comment: More explicitly - you cannot nest Dir loops - you can only have one "context" at any given time.  Likely someone here will help you out if you can explain exactly what changes you're trying to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with the `Dir()` `Function`. To do that you can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. 
This is a sample I wrote that you can easily adapt to your code:

```
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFiles      As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(myPath) 'You must initialize this before
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

'For all files in the folder
For Each oFile In oFiles
    If (oFile Like "*.xls*") Then
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=oFile)

        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
         DoEvents

        'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)

        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents
    End If
Next
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jossy You're welcome. If you'll find this answer helpful, please consider accepting it, so others can benefit from it. :)